# Committee Formation

Tags: combinatorics

A committee is formed containing either the governor or one of the two senators of each of the fifty states. What is the probably that the committee will contain exactly 15 governors?

Answer (score 1):

For each state, we have 1/3 chance of selecting a governor. The probability of one state picking a governor is independent of every other state's pick. This means we can model it binomially. Where X is the number of governors,
$$X = B(50,\frac{1}{3})$$

$$P(X=15)=^{50}C_{15}(\frac{1}{3})^{15}(1-\frac{1}{3})^{50-15}=0.1077$$

Edit:
The probability that any 15 specified states select a governor would be $$(1/3)^{15}$$
The probability that any 15 specified states select a governor whilst the other 35 select a senator is then $$(1/3)^{15}(2/3)^{35}$$ because we need a governor picked these 15 times AND we need a senator picked each of the 35 times.
This is the probability that 15 governors are picked from 15 specified states. However, we don't care which states the 15 come from. Therefore, we need to multiply $(1/3)^{15}(2/3)^{35}$ by the number of different ways of choosing 15 states out of 50 states. The number of ways of choosing 15 out of 50 is denoted by "50 choose 15" or $^{50}C_{15}$.
This leaves us with $^{50}C_{15}(1/3)^{15}(2/3)^{35}$.
If you have not met $^nC_r$ before, here is a link:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: sorry, not familiar with binomial modeling. Could you explain using another method?